# PIC : EEPROM not write properly to 0xFF in PIC18F67K22 controller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, eeprom

I am writing values from 0x50 to 0x3ff in EEPROM of pic18f67k22. Whenever eeprom is getting full, I am writing 0xFF and then after write my data from 0x50 location.
but some time eeprom is not write properly to 0xFF to all location.
I am using simple FOR loop to write 0xFF.

```
 for(i=0; i<900; i++)
 {
     Write_b_eep(0x50+i,0xFF);  //This stores the no of session by incrementing it by one
     Busy_eep();
 }
```

What I am missing?

Comment: One problem I can spot is you shouldn't have `i++` inside the loop, it's already incremented in the for loop.

Comment: oh sorry this is my mistake in writing.i am  changing "i" variable to something else.But problem is not solved.thanks for replay .

Comment: Is writting something other like 0xAA working?? and Can you share function defination of 'Write_b_eep()'?

Comment: yes we can write but some type of index is store on that location.index value is different every time,

Comment: so Before reading location we want to make them 0xFF

Comment: >void Write_b_eep( unsigned int badd, unsigned char bdata );

Comment: @shailkorat I wanted to ask, are you able to write anything other than 0xFF? You said "writting 0xFF fails".... Does writting 0xAA also fails?

Comment: thanks for helping.i resolved my problem.Thanks again for replay .

Comment: @shailkorat What was your problem??